# Cursor options for Adobe Reader in Full Screen mode

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader, cursor

I've made the change from Powerpoint to Beamer for most of my stuff.  There is just one last detail that I need to address.

When I use Adobe Acrobat Reader in Full Screen mode as a presentation tool, the only cursor style I have access to is a silly white hand with a down arrow in the middle of it.  It's not noticeable enough.  I'd like to replace it with something much more noticeable, like the laser pointer option in Powerpoint.

If tried to figure out how to do this in the Windows 10 cursor options -- but I don't even see the hand with the arrow that Acrobat Reader uses in the list that comes up, which makes it very hard to replace.

I'm also quite willing to use any (free) pdf reader that would provide me with the right option, but  Foxit and Sumatra don't seem to do any better.

If I could find a straightforward *artifact-free* way to bring the pdf's into powerpoint, that would work too, but I haven't found one.  If I have to do this slide-by-slide instead of file-by-file, that's not an amenable solution.

Comment: Have you tried the options in this [Tex StackExchange question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84622/is-there-a-specialized-pdf-viewer-for-latex-beamer-presentations-on-linux)? Otherwise, you could try to render to PNGs and then bring those into PowerPoint?

Comment: @davidmneedham -- thanks, but I need to stick with realistically portable options.  The lions share of the suggestions in the thread are for linux, and the recommendations are for a second-screen requirement, which I don't have.   The png export is always an option, but that's what I meant by "Slide-by-Slide"

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution by combing your suggestion of using another pdf viewer - the Sumatra or PDF-XChange Editor - and changing the system mouse pointer as described here  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16761/presentation-software-with-a-cursor-looking-like-a-laser-pointer-instead-of-mous

"Go to the Mouse properties control panel, in the Devices and Pointers control panel section, click on the Pointers tab. Under the Customise scroll box there is a Browse... button. Clicking this allows you to select a .cur file to change the cursor's appearance. However, the built-in cursor files do not provide a laser-like cursor. This is where you have to create your own."

Answer (score 2):

With just Adobe Acrobat:

1. **Cursor size:** With current version of Adobe Acrobat Reader, the mouse pointer size follows the size set in Windows: *Settings → Cursor & Pointer*.
2. **Pen cursor *and* functionality:** in Adobe Acrobat: *Preferences → General → Basic Tools → Use single-key accelerators to access tools (checked)*

   - Then, in full-screen mode, `Shift`+`D` switches to different annotation tools (side effect is that it changes the cursor for some of them). After pressing it about **7 times**, you will get a **pen**. You can use it to draw on the slide as well!
   - `H` will get you your hand cursor back.
   - `S` For a speech-bubble (comment - sticky note) cursor

*(More shortcuts and meaning: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/keyboard-shortcuts.html)*